# How to scp full directories from pi-zero to my pc via ssh

Tags: linux, pi-zero, terminal, scp

Is there any command or way to essentially "scp" a full directory from a raspberry pi to my linux PC using ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `man scp`?

There you would have found following lines:

> -r      Recursively copy entire directories.  Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.

So try `scp -r [...]`.

Comment: Never mind! Hope it'll work now.